# Constants concatenation in Java

Tags: java

If I have constants as

```
public static final String PREFIX = "meter.";

public static final String READING = "reading";

public static final String LEVEL = "level";
```

and I have a code which is

```
run() {
dao.set("meter.reading", x);
dao.set("meter.level", y);
}
```

Given that run() will be called millions of times a day,

would writing the above code as below degrade my performance due to the concatenation ? I would like to maintain constants separated from prefix as they are used with and without prefix in various context

```
run() {
dao.set(PREFIX+READING, x);
dao.set(PREFIX+LEVEL, y);
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I would assume that the compiler would optimize it to exactly what you have already, in which case, no, it wouldn't affect performance.

Answer (score 7):

That will not degrade performance, because you are using compile-time constant expressions.

```
PREFIX+READING
```

The compiler will concatenate it for you, and it will be the same performance as the string literals you've tried.

The [JLS, Section 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), defines constant expressions:

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:

(other options)

> - The unary operators +, -, ~, and ! (but not ++ or --) (§15.15.3, §15.15.4, §15.15.5, §15.15.6)

(other options)

> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

(other options)

> Compile-time constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

Answer (score 0):

I thought there was a tiny performance impact but apparently, I was wrong. Why not just

```
public static final String PREFIX = "meter.";

public static final String READING = PREFIX + "reading";

public static final String LEVEL = PREFIX + "level";
```

Comment: Problem is I will be using "reading" many times in my code. So I dont want to have two constants one for with prefix and one for without.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as it will not create new Strings each time. See rgettman's answer above, and an example here: http://ideone.com/uAu6mO

Comment: Apparently I was wrong :) answer amended to only include my suggestion.  You live and learn

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be optimized and in the String intern cache, and it'll use StringBuilder (depending on your jDK, in older JDKs it would have used StringBuffer) to construct that cached copy once. On my system this prints `true` and then `true`, notice that I'm correctly using '==' on two Strings in this test. Because these strings are all references to the same cached String.

```
public static final String PREFIX = "meter.";
public static final String READING = "reading";
public static final String C = PREFIX + READING;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String a = PREFIX + READING;
  {
    String b = PREFIX + READING;
    System.out.println(a == b);
    System.out.println(a == C);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Strings are immutable, so it has to make a new string object every time you call `run()`. It's a simple operation, and I doubt you will have any trouble with it since you are not working with giant strings and high performance applications.

You should be fine.